# Using react-datepicker alongside redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-datepicker

I'm trying to use redux-form along with react-datepicker but keep getting the following error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `DatePicker`, expected `string`.
```

I have my code setup as follows:

```
  renderDatePicker({input, placeholder, defaultValue="01/01/2018", meta: {touched, error} }) {
    return (
      <div>
            <DatePicker {...input} dateForm="MM/DD/YYYY" selected={input.value ? moment(input.value) : null} />
            {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    )
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit.bind(this))}>
        <Field name='budgetDateDue'  component={this.renderDatePicker} format={(value, name) => value || null} />
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
```

I can't seem to get around this  Warning and I haven't found much online aside from what I have already done.

Answer (score 2):

`input` is an object, and `input.value` is a moment object. `<DatePicker />` is expecting a string, so you'll need to pass it one. Convert the moment object to a string (and format it however you want).

```
<DatePicker 
    {...input} 
    value = {moment(input.value).format('MM-YYYY')} 
    dateForm = "MM/DD/YYYY" 
    selected = {input.value ? moment(input.value) : null} 
/>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Would you mind up voting the answer when you get a chance? :)

Comment: It does not work when having a day already selected, re opening the datepicker and clicking outside. Redux-form 7.3.0

Comment: Make sure you have the `onChange` prop implemented to update your form's state. Your `input.value` needs to update on every `onChange`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom datepicker and pass props to it

```
const datePicker = ({ input, label, type, className, selected, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      <DatePicker {...input}
        selected={selected}
        placeholder={label}
        type={type}
        className={className}
        dropdownMode="select"
      />
      {touched && error && <span className="error_field">{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

And in redux-form component you can do something like this

```
<Field
  name="date_of_birth"
  component={datePicker}
  type="text"
  selected={this.state.date_of_birth}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
  className="form-control"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the samples below worked for me, this was my solution:

```
    class DateField extends Component {

      render() {
        const {
          input,
          meta: { error, touched }, 
        } = this.props;

        return (
          <div>
             <DatePicker
               {...input}
               dateForm="MM/DD/YYYY"
               selected={input.value && input.value}
               onChange={time => {
                input.value = time ? time : null;
               }}
               onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value)}
             />
            {touched && error && <span className="error-block">{error} 
          </span>}
        </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default DateField;
```

Then wrap this in a Form element.